# Как и где настроить префиксы к URL сайта?

Tags: url, веб-сервер

Всех приветствую. Интересует вопрос о добавлении префикса к url.

В данный момент есть сайт `www.site.ru`, есть для него мобильная версия по адресу `https://site.ru/mobile` и небольшое апи по адресу `https://site.ru/api/v1/`.

Вопрос: Какими средствами делаются префиксы к url такого вида:
`https://api.site.ru` для апи сайта и `https://m.site.ru` для мобильной версии?

Comment: В вашем случае, Вам нужно смотреть в сторону доменных имен третьего уровня.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал, просто, в какую сторону рыть.